# How to run .sh in Intellij by right click?

Tags: intellij-idea

After installation intellij idea on new computer I can't run .sh by right click and "Run".
[image]

So before:

1. Just right click on .sh file -> Run

Now:

1. Copy content of .sh
2. Paste it in terminal
3. Press enter :D

How to do it like before?

Comment: Please attach screenshot with right-click context menu on .sh file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. I had to install BashSupport plugin. :)

Comment: Works for me without BashSupport plugin provided that I have the **Shell Script** bundled plugin enabled.